# Receive message "A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted" when trying to debug an App on iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.2

While attempting to debug a build created using the 3.2 SDK on an iPhone device I receive the message "A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted.".

I can clean, rebuild, then install with no error, but if I try to install without cleaning the error shows.

Anyone have an idea as to what might be causing this?

Comment: I keep getting the same thing.  Did you find a solution other than doing Build > Clean All Targets?

Comment: nothing yet, if I do find something I'll self-answer.

Comment: Getting the same error in the latest Xcode/SDK combo as of today. (Xcode 4.3.2)

Comment: Just got it on XCode 4.3.1 / iOS5 and it was just simple bug. I cleaned the project. Rebuild it. Unplugged and plugged back in my iPhone and everything was back to normal. Cheers.

Comment: Just got it on XCode 4.4.1/iOS 5.1 and it went away after restarting XCode, no unplugging or cleaning.

Comment: Just got it on Xcode 4.6.1 / iOS6. Tried to remove derived data and restart Xcode, but no luck :-(

Comment: Got the same thing on XCode v4.6  I shut down XCode completely, started it back up again, Cleaned and Rebuilt the project, and it all worked after that.  So, good to hear that Apple still hasn't fixed this bug!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I found a workaround for the bug.

If you delete the .app file in build/Debug-iphoneos/ before building for the device, the app gets installed without errors.
And there is a simple way to do that before every build.

Make sure you have selected "Device" in the dropdown overview menu.
In XCode go to Project > New target...
Then find "Shell Script target" under MacOSX/Other
Name it and add it to the current project

Now, in the left navigation panel, under targets, expand your newly created target and double-click on Run Script.
In the window that opens replace "# shell script goes here" with "rm -fr build/Debug-iphoneos/*.app" (without the quotes).
Now open your main target preferences and under Direct Dependencies add your newly created target.
Build and Go! :)

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work here. I wiped the whole build directory and am still getting it.

Comment: I found that this worked for me. If you do not want another target, then adding the script to current target works too (build phases tab). Just make sure it's before the copy bundle resources.

Comment: @jernej-strasner: Actually it suffices to "touch" any source file, so a more efficient script would be `touch "${PROJECT_DIR}/MySources/main.m"`

Comment: Cmd+Shift+K before building solved the problem for me.

Comment: The first step works for me. And you indeed have not to delete the .app file manually. Just press `Command + K` in Xcode to clear the build cache and make it work.

Answer (score 25):

This error occurs when there is a **special character in the Product Name**. In my case it was a "?"

If you change the Product Name it automatically updates the "Bundle Name" and "Bundle Display Name" so it is often the best choice to rename an app.

If you want to include special characters in the app name you have to manually **rename the "Bundle Name" and "Bundle Display Name"**

**Bundle Name**: This is the actual app bundle name in the file system such as "Awesome App.app". It is generally not visible to the user.

**Bundle Display Name**: This is a **short name displayed under the app icon** on the device. Since the bundle name would be truncated to "Awes…tion" you have the option to have a shorter name which fits better such as "Awesome App". It should be similar to the App Store name (set in iTunes Connect)

Comment: Saved my day! Was a freaking "?" for me, too

Comment: Wrong, the bundle name (CFBundleName) is not the name of the app in the Store. It is the name of the app on the filesystem (with .app) at the end). Users normally never see the CFBundleName.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet I updated the answer. Thank for highlighting it!

Comment: For me it was a pipe symbol in the product name: |

Comment: For me it was a French letter accented and uppercase (`À`). Weirdly this one causes the issue, whereas lowercase accented letters work well… (`à`, `é`, etc).

Answer (score 12):

This is pretty clearly a bug in the 3.2 SDK, but I don't want to downgrade.  I've found that doing a Clean by pushing `Command+Shift+K`, then `Return` is pretty fast before pushing `Command+R` to build.

Comment: I have had this problem every time I build for the Device since updating to the 3.2 SDK.  Annoying, but easy enough to work around.

Comment: Easy to say if you have a small Workspace.  Cleaning and re-building adds around a minute onto my launch time which, over the space of a day, could be a much as an hour wasted waiting for the app to re-build.

Answer (score 7):

Xcode 8, reason of the "A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted." was that target was signed with an enterprise provision profile.

Comment: So is there a solution?  I have this problem and I have an enterprise app.

Comment: if you try to run the target signing it with enterprise you will get this message or some other weird error. For debuging you should sign the target with development certificate. Or if you can't use development certificate you should use logs or other debug technics.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it happened when no changes were made. Make a change to any file and run again.

Comment: For me it's the same, but I'm using react-native.

Answer (score 3):

This can have several causes. The fastest way to figure out what is causing it is to go into Xcode, Window menu, Devices, then click the reveal button at the bottom of the pane to show the Console. Now attempt to run. You should see log output that names the specific files it is complaining about.

Most of the solutions previously posted are just artificial ways of getting Xcode to regenerate the contents of the build folder and/or re-sign the files.

In my case, my WatchKit extension was somehow acquiring references to Cocoapods frameworks that were only targeted toward the main app so they got signed during the build, then pruned later (as they were not used). Then on device, iOS complained that they were missing from the .appex folder for the extension. I ended up not needing any pods in the extension so I just removed them all and removed the extension as a target, then did some minor cleanup to remove the pod-related debris left in the build steps. Now everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

(SOLVED) This is a weird one. I tried everything I could find. Eventually I changed the product name from "Unit Tests (device)" to "Device Unit Tests" - removing the brackets. Now everything works. The spaces in it appear to be fine.

Previously on stackoverflow:
I've just run into this bug with two static library projects. One builds and tests using the GHUnit test runner on the device without a problem. The other projects will not install and gets this error. That means it's something thats different between these two projects. I've so far tried wiping the build directory, taking spaces out of the executable name, and various clean and builds as suggested here.

Answer (score 1):

Same for me, thought it has something to do with multiple targets etc. because I changed a lot there. But it's highly possible that it's a Bug in the 3.2.2 release since I did not test extensively in this sdk version before the massive target changes in my project.

Answer (score 1):

solved my issue!!!

I found out by accident that somehow a space " " found it's way into the Product Name of my app so it was called "First Second.app" instead of "FirstSecond.app". After deleting the space the issue was gone!

I changed it here:
right click on target
Get Info
Build Tab
Packaging Section
Product Name <- The name here will be used for the bundle (.app) name

Hope this helps, let me know!

Cheers,
nils

Comment: I double checked my settings and this wasn't the problem, I'm leaning towards thinking that it is, in fact, a bug in the new 3.2 SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I could solved by changing project name.

```
[project]-[Rename] menu. "phase1 (new)" -> "pahse1"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this same error, but intermittently.  I tried all the above and it still didn't work.  Today I found what was causing it.

The error seems to occur when editing a xib in interface builder.  If you try to run while the   interface builder is open in xcode it will cause the above error.  To solve just close the interface builder editor.  i.e. just select a code file from your project so you are in the Source Editor.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest (and probably most common cause) appears to be rebuilding without any changes.

So the simplest thing to cure it is to make a trivial change to a source file (such as adding a space, then deleting it), and then rebuilding.

If this doesn't work, feel free to try all the other answers here.

For months, I'd get this error without realizing it was due to such a simple cause.  I'd usually do a Clean Build to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

When I created ipa through terminal using xcodebuild commands, ipa created but while installing it I was getting same error. exportOptionsPlist solved my issue.

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath  projectPath/myapp.xcarchive  -exportPath  projectPath/myApp.ipa  -exportOptionsPlist  ProjectFolder/exportPlist.plist
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Quit and restarting XCode worked.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was related to the provisioning profile settings.  The clue to this was that debug builds were installing ok, but release builds were not.  I wanted to test a release build, so I ran the scheme with that build configuration.

I fixed it by duplicating the Release Configuration, then modifying those fields in the Build Settings to have the same provisioning stuff as if I am debugging it.

(Adding another build configuration will give you headaches if you are using Cocoapods however, then you'll have to modify your Podfile)

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same thing, when installing on a iPod Touch.  I can't link for the simulator (for other reasons), so can't say whether the problem occurs there.

Yes, rebuilding clean or deleting the app from the device allows me to install again.  Neither are desirable, iterative solutions!

The minimal "cleaning" I've come across as a work around is manually deleting the Foo.app in the build/Debug-iphoneos directory.

Comment: FYI, 
http://blog.shirl.com/2010/01/29/xcode-3-2-2-beta-issue-install-on-device/
password: first 4 digits of Xcode IDE component version for the 3.2.2 beta release

Answer (score 0):

it seems this is a bug in xcode 3.2.2:
[iphonedevsdk](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/39173-same-signed-resource-has-been-added-modified-deleted-error-xcode-3-2-2-a.html)

Comment: ... and is still a bug in v4.6  (June 2013)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Xcode 3.2.1 when I put a + in my app name.  Specifically the "product name" in the build settings.  It is fine to have a + in the bundle name in your Info.plist.  The same probably applies to other punctuation characters.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window > Organizer > Projects > Find your project and delete derived data

Answer (score 0):

I got this error intermittently while installing app using iPhone config utility on Windows7. `Following solution works - Go to C:\Users\{lanusername}\AppData\Local\Temp and delete app specific folders (e.g. abc.app) and try installing app again.`

Answer (score 0):

I reported this bug on ICU (Windows versions) to Apple in June 2011. With the following workarounds:

## The workaround is this ....

Win XP

1) Close ICU

2) Delete the temp folder:          c:\Documents and Settings\[username]\Local Settings\Temp\[AppName].app

3) Delete the deploy folder:         c:\Documents and Settings\[username]\Application Data\AppleComputer\MobileDevice

4) Restart ICU. Drag in the App and install normally.

============================

Win 7

1) Close ICU

2) Delete the temp folder:           c:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\[AppName].app

3) Delete the deploy folder:          c:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Apple Computer\MobileDevice\Applications\[AppName].app

4) Restart ICU. Drag in the App and install normally.

=========================================================

Answer (score 0):

I simply rebuilt my app, and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. After wasting lot of time I realized that my product name has a special character "?" which cased the problem

Answer (score 0):

Having the DerivedData folder at a network location caused this problem for me.

After trying everything else, I found out my workstation couldn't agree with the University server about what the time was. (It thought everything was always modified). I also had to clean for every rebuild to avoid that frustrating message.

In the end I gave up and built locally, changing Xcode > Preferences > Locations ... feeling altogether pretty dumb for having ever built over the network.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this issues on XCode_6.3.1. We were building a AppleWatch app, with an extension. We do have a bunch of Pods.. After debugging the issue for almost a bunch of hours, what we found was that there was an issue with the way a file was adde to the project..

It seems like some references to a unused file was sitting in the iPhone App, though it was used in the Watch App.. It turns out that the error XCode was showing was totally useless.

After removing this file and re adding it back to the project the project started working fine & was able to install to the device. To make it even harder to debug the issues, the debug version was installed without an issue, but was unable to install the norman version..

Make sure you add your files to the right target and, look at git history and see if there are lingering fragments that are added to the wrong target.

Comment: i am facing the same error now. Can you elaborate how can I identify the file to remove to solve problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very general error message indicating something is wrong during the validation process of the code signature. To find out the specific error, you can go to Xcode->Window->Devices and check your device log.

In my case, I have following console spew

Feb  1 18:53:07 iPod-touch installd[40] : 0x1001f8000 -[MICodeSigningVerifier performValidationWithError:]: 192: Failed to verify code signature of  : 0xe8008017 (Signed resources have been added, removed, or modified)

Check on this 3rd party framework again, I found an extra CodeResources file under the framework root. Remove that file fixed the problem.