# Error while releasing applications in to iPod

Tags: iphone

I am getting the error **A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted** while releasing applications in to my iPod. previously by mistake i tried releasing the same application in to iPod but it didnt run as there was errors in my application. After rectifying the errors when i tried releasing the app its showing the above mentioned error..
 Pleasing can anyone help me..

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a clean build (<kbd>Cmd-Shift-K</kbd> to clean all targets). If that does not work, look into a [previous question on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157964).