# Error in installing app through iphone configuration utility

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

i am creating a build for a app and installing it in device from iphone configuration utility and it is working very well.

but , in my friends device it is not working , he has same provisioning profile what i have, 
in his iphone configuration utility when he goes for install it is showing error

***Could not install application on device. Error: a signed resources has been added , modified or deleted.***

any solution for this ?
may i install provision profile again ? or any other problem ? it is working fine in my mac

Comment: follow this link, i hope it helps

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157964/receive-message-a-signed-resource-has-been-added-modified-or-deleted-when-tr

Comment: this problem is not happen when i am going to build , but it happens when i am installing it in device by iphone configuration utility..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Receive message "A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted" when trying to debug an App on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157964/receive-message-a-signed-resource-has-been-added-modified-or-deleted-when-tr)

thanks to  Istalla Raju...

but still , it may be a problem of iphone configuration utility.

i am not sure about this.

Answer (score 5):

On `windows 7` I was getting the same error and the only way to solve it was deleting the application information stored at c:\users\\AppData\Local\Temp , there you will find  a folder named as the ios application giving problems, delete it and also delete the app from iphone configuration utility and you are done

Comment: In reality it's C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Temp and AppData is hidden by default

Comment: This worked for me too on Windows 7 - just delete the file from the temp directory, remove from iPhone configuration tool and reinstall.  Saved me much frustration - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1. Change the name to a shorter one on desktop
2. Delete the older file if present on iPhone Configuration Utility
3. Re-install

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the source file and try installing again. It worked for me.