# Xcode 4 - A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted

Tags: ios, xcode, signing

Issue:

I have created an app, distributed an ad-hoc version and successfully uploaded it under Organizer - Devices. So far so good. Now, i've tried a 2nd app. When i uploaded this one, i get the following message:

**A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted.**

I googeld for a while and tried the following things:

- avoid special chars in the projectname
- clear the build
- delete derived data under Organizer - Projects
- renew my Certificate
- renew all my provisioning profiles
- i've made a new and minimalistic project

It failed all. Same message every time.

Hopefully someone can help me, please.

Comment: An error I got with my client, was a bad deziping in Windows, or an exploration made by a Windows user in the .app (seen as a file in Mac OS, but as a folder in Windows) which modified (the Windows Explorer) the app.

Comment: Running `codesign -vv path/to/YourApp.app` should tell you which resources have been added / modified / deleted. That may help you work out what's going wrong.

Comment: SOLVED: @Larme thanks for the hint. I'd linked my www dir absolute to webdav. Obviously, that was the problem. So, i've linked my www dir relative to one on my mac, copied all www files from webdav to the mac dir and BAM, it worked. Thank you very much, Larme

Comment: I've also seen this message when I've deleted the app as Xcode was copying it to the device. Pro tip: don't do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157964/receive-message-a-signed-resource-has-been-added-modified-or-deleted-when-tr

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and what worked for me was deleting the Derived Data (in Organizer).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you created the app ID for both apps in the Apple Developer Portal. Usually 'com.companyname.appname' as Bundle Identifier
- Create both certificates and download them.
- Check if you can open those certificates on your keychain. If you see an arrow next to the certificate name you can use the certificate. That means that you have the matching key for that certificate.
- Create both provisioning profiles as Ad-Hoc and assign the App ID you just created.
- If you have not added your devices to the device list, do it in this step.
- Add the device to both provisioning profiles
- Download and open the provisioning profiles (A tool I find very useful to manage provisioning profiles is the iPhone Configuration Utility)
- In XCode on your project file select the target and in the 'Summary' tab type the Bundle Identifier.
- Now go to Build Settings tab and select Code Signing and select your Bundle identifier
- Clean and run.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are having two apps with same bundle name in your derived data folder. Simply delete one then the bug gone.

Comment: Didn't work for me - deleting the entire derived data folder had no effect