# Unable to use a XCFramework on watchOS

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, apple-watch, xcframework

I'm developing an iOS application which uses a separate SDK for some common business logic. That SDK is developed in another separate project which creates a dynamic binary framework as an output. The bundle type of that framework is a XCFramework as Apple suggested to use starting from Xcode 11. The content of this XCFramework is the following one:

```
MySDK.xcframework
├── Info.plist
├── ios-arm64
│   └── MySDK.framework
│   ├── Headers
│   │   ├── MySDK.h
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── Info.plist
│   ├── Modules
│   │   └── module.modulemap
│   ├── MySDK
│   └── _CodeSignature
│   └── CodeResources
├── ios-x86_64-simulator
│   └── MySDK.framework
│   ├── Headers
│   │   ├── MySDK.h
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── Info.plist
│   ├── Modules
│   │   └── module.modulemap
│   ├── MySDK
│   └── _CodeSignature
│   └── CodeResources
└── watchos-armv7k_arm64_32
    └── MySDK.framework
    ├── Headers
    │   ├── MySDK.h
    │   ├── ...
    ├── Info.plist
    ├── Modules
    │   └── module.modulemap
    ├── MySDK
    └── _CodeSignature
    └── CodeResources
```

If I use the XCFramework on the iOS target, everything works as expected and just importing the MySDK module I can use the SDK without any problem.

However, if I import the same framework on the Watch Extension target, and run it into a real iWatch it gives us the following error:

Details

```
Unable to install "Watch"
  Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
  Code: -402620393
  --
  A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted.
  Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
  Code: -402620393
  User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 364477;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8008017)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0 DTDeviceKitBase 0x000000011ff4681a DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 233
    1 DTDeviceKitBase 0x000000011ff87f70 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2 DVTFoundation 0x000000010697e385 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 73
    3 DTDeviceKitBase 0x000000011ff87ca8 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1654
    4 IDEiOSSupportCore 0x000000011fdfee91 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.352 + 4165
    5 DVTFoundation 0x0000000106ab1a10 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6 DVTFoundation 0x0000000106ab3652 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1194
    7 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff729b6583 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff729b750e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff729bcace _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
    10 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff729bd452 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363
    11 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff729c6a9e _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 598
    12 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff72c116fc _pthread_wqthread + 290
    13 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff72c10827 start_wqthread + 15
  );
}

--

System Information

macOS Version 10.15.3 (Build 19D76)
Xcode 11.4 (16134)
```

The SDK target is compiled for the watchOS architecture as you guys can see the corresponding folder within its contents (watchos-armv7k_arm64_32). Also, I've ensured it was correctly compiled using the LIPO tool.

What I have tried:

- Follow related issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157964/receive-message-a-signed-resource-has-been-added-modified-or-deleted-when-tr), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402671/xcode-4-a-signed-resource-has-been-added-modified-or-deleted) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29878377/xcode-6-3-1-a-signed-resource-has-been-added-modified-or-deleted-issue) without any
  success.
- Duplicate the XCFramework with only watchos architecture and include both frameworks in the project but targeting different
  destinations. It does not work either.
- Try all framework embedding options: Embed & sign or Embed without signing. It gives the error shown above.

I'm a bit lost and I don't know what else I could try. Anyone who could shed some light on this would be very appreciated.

Comment: Hey! Did you figure this out?

Comment: Not yet, still trying to find an answer for it.

Answer (score 1):

I workarounded the same issue building custom framework with `staticlib` Mach-O Type:

1. Open Project Settings of your custom framework (MySDK, for example).
2. Choose target for watchOS.
3. Find Mach-O Type and set it to `Static Library`. [Mach-O Type: Static Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFdCC.png)
4. Build frameworks and xcframework.

Now you can link your application with MySDK.xcframework. Do not embed xcframework for watchOS target in the application - it should be linked statically.

Comment: could you add more of an explanation of what you did?

Comment: @rhavelka I have just updated the answer. Please check it.