# Error "A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted" when installing app add hoc

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6

While attempting to install my application on my device by AddHoc I receive the error "**A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted**"

This question might appear to have at least 20 duplicates however I have tried everything I can find being suggested, I've:

- Cleaned my project
- Deleted and revoked all certificates and provisioning profiles
- Re-created and downloaded them
- I have no special characters in my product name
- The device ID is on the AddHoc profile
- Deleted derived data

When I run `codesign -vv --deep path/to/payload/app.app` it tells me "**satisfies its Designated Requirement**"

I am running iOS8 beta 4, Yosemite beta 4, and Xcode6 beta 1

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: It's a long shot, but how about updating to Xcode 6 beta 4?

Comment: Xcode6 beta 4 has some pretty serious problems when compiling my code but I'm working on modifying the code to work with Xcode6 beta 4

Comment: @BrunoWerminghoff I've checked out your profile and you seem like you might be able to help me out with the problem I have with Xcode6 beta4  [Here's a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089448/ios8-bitcast-requires-both-operands-to-be-pointer-or-neither)

Comment: Just try to clean the build directory (cmd+shift+k) and run directly again. See answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2207055/1677041

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Bruno Werminghoff was right, it appears that AddHoc deployment of iOS8 applications (and presumably any in the past or future) will not work unless they are archived with the most recent Xcode.  When I updated to Xcode6 beta 4 the problem was gone.