# Xcode6: Failed to copy nib file resource into .app directory

Tags: ios, xcode, resources, xcode6, ios-simulator

Ok, I'm not sure what I modified on project.pbxproj file. Here is the result, I've checked the app target build phrase *Copy Bundle Resources* and all the xib files are there. If I move the whole app *DerivedData* folder to trash, reset the iOS Simulator, then build it, the app works fine, also I found all the nib files are included in $/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Foo.app/ (no localization for nib file). I ran it, the view controller related show very well.

If I **don't** clean the derived data folder, build & run the app at the second time, now here is the problem, all the xib related view/view controller will show blank or crash. I checked the nib files over there, all of them disappear, but the image resources still exist.

**How did it do when build/copy the nib resources?**

Another found: some *temporarily* files are generated in $/Build/Intermediates/.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/.build, if I clean the .build **only**, rebuild it, it works fine.

I could solve this by script to remove the .build when building every time, but still wonder why.

Environment: Xcode 6.1.1/6.1

Please, any suggestions are grateful, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the root issue by myself.

That's because I ran a script to delete the .app before building the project every time, there is a historical issue that I tried to solve the Xcode6 bug. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157964/receive-message-a-signed-resource-has-been-added-modified-or-deleted-when-tr).

Wrong script caused this, my bad.