# A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted

Tags: ios, ios8-share-extension

I have this error ever since I have added a share extension to the iOS project. The error pops up when the xcode is finished building the project and just before it could launch the app on the device. So I traced down the device log for more information and it is as below.

```
Jul 24 11:04:36 cloudy45mans-iPhone-6 installd[3502] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Jul 24 11:04:38 cloudy45mans-iPhone-6 installd[3502] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Jul 24 11:04:39 cloudy45mans-iPhone-6 installd[3502] <Error>: resource modified: /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.W3ZgdD/extracted/Payload/Present.app/PlugIns/shareextension.appex/Assets.car
Jul 24 11:04:39 cloudy45mans-iPhone-6 installd[3502] <Error>: resource modified: /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.W3ZgdD/extracted/Payload/Present.app/PlugIns/shareextension.appex/MPNotification.storyboardc/MPNotificationViewController.nib
Jul 24 11:04:39 cloudy45mans-iPhone-6 installd[3502] <Error>: resource modified: /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.W3ZgdD/extracted/Payload/Present.app/PlugIns/shareextension.appex/MPNotification.storyboardc/puo-Hy-QiQ-view-Wch-Xc-Avw.nib
Jul 24 11:04:39 cloudy45mans-iPhone-6 installd[3502] <Error>: resource modified: /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.W3ZgdD/extracted/Payload/Present.app/PlugIns/shareextension.appex/MPSurvey.storyboardc/Info.plist
Jul 24 11:04:39 cloudy45mans-iPhone-6 installd[3502] <Error>: resource modified: /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.W3ZgdD/extracted/Payload/Present.app/PlugIns/shareextension.appex/MPSurvey.storyboardc/MPSurveyMultipleChoiceQuestionViewController.nib
Jul 24 11:04:39 cloudy45mans-iPhone-6 installd[3502] <Error>: resource modified: /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.W3ZgdD/extracted/Payload/Present.app/PlugIns/shareextension.appex/MPSurvey.storyboardc/MPSurveyNavigationController.nib
Jul 24 11:04:39 cloudy45mans-iPhone-6 installd[3502] <Error>: resource modified: /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.W3ZgdD/extracted/Payload/Present.app/PlugIns/shareextension.appex/MPSurvey.storyboardc/MPSurveyTextQuestionViewController.nib
Jul 24 11:04:39 cloudy45mans-iPhone-6 installd[3502] <Error>: resource modified: /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.W3ZgdD/extracted/Payload/Present.app/PlugIns/shareextension.appex/MPSurvey.storyboardc/RIP-po-dgx-view-cp6-lZ-a9t.nib
Jul 24 11:04:39 cloudy45mans-iPhone-6 installd[3502] <Error>: resource modified: /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.W3ZgdD/extracted/Payload/Present.app/PlugIns/shareextension.appex/MPSurvey.storyboardc/V5X-Ik-MvF-view-dcL-M9-gG3.nib
Jul 24 11:04:39 cloudy45mans-iPhone-6 installd[3502] <Error>: resource modified: /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.W3ZgdD/extracted/Payload/Present.app/PlugIns/shareextension.appex/MPSurvey.storyboardc/tDf-fb-udT-view-LG7-cL-aRp.nib
Jul 24 11:04:39 cloudy45mans-iPhone-6 installd[3502] <Error>: resource modified: /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.W3ZgdD/extracted/Payload/Present.app/PlugIns/shareextension.appex/THDateDay.nib
Jul 24 11:04:39 cloudy45mans-iPhone-6 installd[3502] <Error>: resource modified: /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.W3ZgdD/extracted/Payload/Present.app/PlugIns/shareextension.appex/THDatePickerViewController.nib
Jul 24 11:04:39 cloudy45mans-iPhone-6 installd[3502] <Error>: 0x1004a0000 -[MICodeSigningVerifier performValidationWithError:]: 188: Failed to verify code signature of <MIPluginKitPluginBundle : path = /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.W3ZgdD/extracted/Payload/Present.app/PlugIns/shareextension.appex identifier = com.present.iphone.shareextension type = App Extension> : 0xe8008017 (Signed resources have been added, removed, or modified)
Jul 24 11:04:39 cloudy45mans-iPhone-6 installd[3502] <Error>: 0x1004a0000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Verification stage failed
Jul 24 11:04:40 cloudy45mans-iPhone-6 streaming_zip_conduit[3503] <Error>: 0x100384000 __MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices_block_invoke240: Returned error Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=13 "Failed to verify code signature of <MIPluginKitPluginBundle : path = /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.W3ZgdD/extracted/Payload/Present.app/PlugIns/shareextension.appex identifier = com.present.iphone.shareextension type = App Extension> : 0xe8008017 (Signed resources have been added, removed, or modified)" UserInfo=0x126e25b10 {LibMISErrorNumber=-402620393, LegacyErrorString=ApplicationVerificationFailed, SourceFileLine=188, FunctionName=-[MICodeSigningVerifier performValidationWithError:], NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to verify code signature of <MIPluginKitPluginBundle : path = /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.W3ZgdD/extracted/Payload/Present.app/PlugIns/shareextension.appex identifier = com.present.iphone.shareextension type = App Extension> : 0xe8008017 (Signed resources have been added, removed, or modified)}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't find a solution yet but this post help me to fix the issue temporarily.

[Receive message "A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted" when trying to debug an App on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157964/receive-message-a-signed-resource-has-been-added-modified-or-deleted-when-tr)

Choose "Edit Scheme..." from the dropdown menu beside stop button in xcode. Expand the "Run" in the left panel. Choose "Pre-actions" and click the plus sign in the bottom of right panel. Add the code in the following line, close and run. You need replace the path with your project path.

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/shareextension.*

rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/shareextension.*
```