# In Xcode, build for running is succeed, but App installation failed

Tags: xcode

I want to install the app I had previously deleted back into Xcode.

'build for running' is succeed in xcode, but App installation failed when I run at connected iphone. The error messege is 'A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted'.

---

i'm using this profile.

[image: Screen Shot]

---

I solved this problem by changing the profile and code signing identity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157964/receive-message-a-signed-resource-has-been-added-modified-or-deleted-when-tr

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Receive message "A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted" when trying to debug an App on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157964/receive-message-a-signed-resource-has-been-added-modified-or-deleted-when-tr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your profile has been expired. Check your profile from developers.apple.com.

You can take a look on [this link](https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/204972657-iOS-Reference-Updating-Your-Provisioning-Profiles-to-Accept-Push-Notifications?mobile_site=true)

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

You must need to user developer profile to installed directly into your device from xCode.

Distribution is only when you want to upload app on AppStore.

As in your screen shots, you are using Distribution profile for same. Kindly use developer profile to installed.

Comment: I solved this problem by changing the profile and code signing identity.
thank you